# mail_form is not working using ruby on rails4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am using a gem mail_form and a gem simple_form in ruby on rails 4.But when i send a mail an error generate that execution time expired.I dont know what is wrong with my form.

```
   def create
     @contact = Contact.new(params[:contact])
     if @contact.valid?
       @contact.deliver  # error line is here
     else 
       render :new
     end
   end
```

Comment: I tried to clean up the code to make it readable but I got lost with what you're actually trying to do - `end`/`else` doesn't make sense, and you're missing an `end`.

Comment: There's no meaning of putting `else` after `end`

Answer (score 0):

Here is some of the code we're using:

---

**Controller**

```
#Form submitted
def enquire
    @message = ContactForm.new(enquiry_params)
    flash.clear

    if @message.valid?
        @message.deliver
        flash[:notice] = "Message Sent Thank You!"
    else
        flash[:error] = "Sorry, You Got Errors!"
    end

    respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to contact_index_path }
        format.js
    end
end

private

def enquire_params
     params.require(:contact_form).permit(:name, :email, :message)
end
```

---

**Mailer**

We've set it up so that the form uses a mailer called 'ContactForm`:

```
#app/mailers/contact_form.rb
class ContactForm < MailForm::Base
  attribute :name,      validate: true
  attribute :email,     validate: /\A([\w\.%\+\-]+)@([\w\-]+\.)+([\w]{2,})\z/i
  attribute :message

  #Simple SPAM Protection (needs to remain blank)
  attributes :nickname,  captcha: true

  # Declare the e-mail headers. It accepts anything the mail method
  # in ActionMailer accepts.
  def headers
    {
      subject: "Website Enquiry",
      to: AppConfig["company"]["enquiry"],
      from: %("#{name}" <#{email}>)
    }
  end
end
```

---

**View**

This then uses:

```
#app/views/enquiry_mailer/new_message.text
Email: <%= @message.email %>

Subject: <%= @message.subject %>

Message: <%= @message.body %>
```

Are you sure you have all of this?